# Please identify this bug/insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Ten of these bugs were found behind my bed. I live in Northern California.
The bug is 5mm in length.

[image: Here is the bug (5mm)]

Comment: It seems to me a kind of larva.

Comment: I think you are correct. After doing a web search, I believe it is carpet beetle larva. Here is a link: http://www.bugzapperpestcontrol.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Varied-Carpet-Beetle-Larva.jpg

Comment: Sure looks like the picture. If your room is carpeted and the carpet is edible, e.g. wool versus a total synthetic, that might offer some conformation.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  I will mark it as a duplicate as per rg255's suggestion. My room is fortunately not carpeted, but I had some old rope behind my bed, and I think they were eating that.

Comment: Carpet beetle larvae  feed on basically any organic matter... Also, yes, this is definitely a carrpet beetle larvae